# Github not triggering job when pull request is created to branch

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I need to run a jenkins job when PR is created to my staging branch in github. The jenkins will run some test cases and return the results to github and after that only we can merge the PR to the staging branch.

I'm using `GitHub pull request builder` plugin in jenkins. But my job in jenkins is not getting triggered when PR is created. The webhook from github is show 200 status and its working to buid a jenkins job for github push.

I followed https://medium.com/@mreigen/integrate-jenkins-builds-into-github-pull-requests-33bc053d6210 steps.

Can anybody help me with This!

Answer (score 1):

Check the Jenkins logs first.

For example, [jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin issue 286](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/286#issuecomment-195849874) mentioned:

> It looks like GitHub is sending the wrong kind of events.
>
> - The plugin only accepts pull_request and issue_comment events.
> - GitHub is sending a push event, so I am not sure but you might have configured the webhook using a different plugin?
>
> Check your master config and make sure you are only telling the job triggers to use webhooks. Also, make sure you have checked the box in each job you want that says to build using webhooks.

[Issue 603](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/603) involved the option "Use github hooks for build triggering", but mention an Hook URL issue.

Comment: Then jenkins logs shows the following:


[Mon Mar 23 13:30:18 UTC 2020] Received Pull request #33 opened in repository CREATED event from 192.30.252.97 ⇒ https://jenkins.domin.com:8080/github-webhook/ with timestamp Mon Mar 23 13:30:13 UTC 2020
[Mon Mar 23 13:30:18 UTC 2020] Finished processing Pull request #33 opened in repository CREATED event from 192.30.252.97 ⇒ https://jenkins.domain.com:8080/github-webhook/ with timestamp Mon Mar 23 13:30:13 UTC 2020. Matched 0.

Comment: @Nijo Strange. I don't see "Received Pull Request" in the code of https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/search?q=Received+Pull+request&type=Code. Maybe I am not referring to the right plugin?

Comment: i'm using "GitHub pull request builder" plugin. Please see the doc shared above. I found similar steos in many docs

Comment: @Nijo OK, so it is the same. Maybe the GitHub API has changed since the last release of that plugin (2018). You might consider a more modern option: GitHub Actions: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner-github-actions

Comment: I already have jenkins up and running and for using Github actions i need to upgrade my current github team plan